# How to expose Webpack-built library as function?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a JavaScript library which is essentially a Vue.js component bundled together with Vue itself. The project was started via the `vue-cli` and is packaged with Webpack.

When this library gets imported via a `<script>` tag, I'd like it to expose a single function like:

```
Mapboard({div: '#some-div')
```

The library itself is currently just:

```
export default (opts) => console.log('hello')
```

I tweaked my Webpack config to set a library name:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    library: 'Mapboard'
  }
}
```

which successfully exposes a global called `Mapboard`, but it's object, not a function:

```
{
  __esModule: true,
  default: function (e) {...}
}
```

Is there any way to prevent Webpack from exporting this as an ES6 module? I'd like it to just be the function exported by the module, as shown above.

Comment: try `library: 'commonjs Mapboard'` or add `output.libraryTarget: 'commonjs'`

Comment: @Maximus I'm getting an error in the browser `exports is not defined`

Comment: what script loader do you use?

Comment: @Maximus `vue-loader` and `babel-loader`

Comment: @Jura did you solve your problem by reading that article?

Comment: Could you make it work @Rob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to this webpack 2 official article: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

That is for ES5 and ES6, if you are building your library using TypeScript, you probably need extra configuration for typings...

Answer (score 1):

http://siawyoung.com/coding/javascript/exporting-es6-modules-as-single-scripts-with-webpack.html

This article helps a lot.The core point to solve this problem is:

> The fix for this is simple: simply write a file that imports those ES6 modules the ES6 way, but exports them in nodeJS module.exports style. Webpack will then handle them correctly!

That's right!Just change your function into :

```
function foo(opts) {
  console.log('hello');
}
module.exports = foo;
```

And everything should work as expected.

**NOTE:Code write like this may not work:**

```
module.exports = function foo(opts) {
  console.log('hello');
}
```